# Can't set color in paintComponent

Tags: java, paint, paintcomponent

I'm writing a *"paint"* analog program *(it draws rectangles and lines from HashSets)*, and I have a problem to color dots and lines. Here's my code:

```
package paint;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Draw extends JComponent {
private HashSet<Point2D> points = new HashSet<>();
private HashSet<Line2D> lines = new HashSet<>();
private final int WIDTH = 5, HEIGHT = 5;
private Point2D prevPoint, nextPoint;

public Draw() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mousePressed(e);
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                prevPoint = e.getPoint();
                points.add(prevPoint);
                repaint();
            }
        }

    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseDragged(e);
            nextPoint = e.getPoint();
            Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(prevPoint, nextPoint);
            lines.add(line);
            prevPoint = nextPoint;
            repaint();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (Point2D p : points) {
        int x = (int)p.getX() - (WIDTH / 2);
        int y = (int)p.getY() - (HEIGHT / 2);
        g2d.setColor(getColor());
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g2d.drawRect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    for (Line2D l : lines) {
        g2d.setColor(getColor());
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(WIDTH));
        g2d.draw(l);
    }
}

public Color getColor() {
    Tools t = new Tools();
    return t.getColor();
}

}


package paint;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tools extends JPanel {
private Color color;
private JButton button;
private ButtonColor bc;

public Tools() {
    makeButton("black", Color.BLACK);
    makeButton("green", Color.GREEN);
}

public void makeButton(String name, final Color color) {
    bc = new ButtonColor(name, color);
    add(new JButton(bc));
}

private class ButtonColor extends AbstractAction {

    public ButtonColor(String name, Color color) {
        putValue(NAME, name);
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Choose " + name.toLowerCase() + " color");
        putValue("color", color);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        color = (Color) getValue("color");
        System.out.println(color);
    }

}

public Color getColor() {
    System.out.println(color);
    return color;
}

}
```

Now, when I pressed black or green button console printed `java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]` or `java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]`. But when I tried to draw lines it printed `null`.

How could I change method `Draw.getColor()` to make changing color possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time `paintComponent` is called, you are using what ever color was set last.

What you need to do is associate the color with the current activity, so that when `paintComponent` is called, you can look up the color for the shape you are drawing.

You could create a custom class which contained the `Line` and color values and add those to your List.  When you paint the `Line`, you would look up the color to use as well

You would need to do the same thing for your points

Comment: Good idea! I have changed that and code looks more readable and flexible.

Comment: But the problem was with private Color color in class Tool. I changed that to private static Color color and now it works fine. Of course the question is: is it safe, or are there other bad things that could appear?

Comment: Nope. The color should be contextual to the current element you are painting, not the canvas you're painting it to